# Illegal string offset laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Below is my query which fetches name of user

```
$userName4 = User::where('_id', '=', $userId4)->first()->name;
```

Output

```
CHANDRA PRAKASH SHARMA
```

Then

```
$data[$flevel][$userName2[0]['name']][$userName3[0]['name']][$userName4] = $eachSetData4[$level[2]];
// $data[South][Sajeev MT][Jayasheela G][CHANDRA PRAKASH SHARMA] = '1213we23121ws';
```

But I am getting following error,

```
Illegal string offset 'CHANDRA PRAKASH SHARMA'
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your issue involves the `$eachSetData4[$level[2]]` array (because this error typically occurs when trying to retrieve data - not when defining it...). Are you sure that `$eachSetData4[]` has an array key that is the same as the value the `$level[2]`?